# Wie und wann verwendet man “halt”?

Tags: word-usage, difference, particle

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Sätzen?

> (1) Ich kaufe mir halt ein Auto.
>
> (2) Ich kaufe mir ein Auto.

Wie und wann werden diese Partikeln (*halt*, *eben*) verwendet?

Comment: Ich habe _so_ aus dem ersten Beispiel entfernt. Der Unterschied zwischen _ein_ und _so ein_ wäre ein anderes Thema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Das ist halt so" - Hier drückt "halt" einfach aus, das man keine Erklärung für etwas hat.
Manchmal ist ein sehr schwierig, die Nuance von solchen Füllwörtern anzugeben, besonders bei Einzelsätzen. In "Dann kaufe ich mir halt ein Auto", könnte "halt" eine gewisse Resignation ausdrücken, zB die Anschaffung eines Autos wäre finanziell schwierig, aber für die neue Arbeitsstelle ist ein Auto notwendig: Gut, dann nehme ich halt einen Kredit auf und kaufe mir (halt) ein Auto.